# Xamarin Android Background Notification Custom Sound

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

is it possible to use custom sounds in xamarin android for background notification? I didnt find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! Here's an example:

```
 var pathToPushSound = $"android.resource://com.your.package/raw/{soundName}";
 var soundUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(pathToPushSound);
 var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context)
            .SetContentTitle("TITLE")
            .SetContentText("TEXT")
            .SetPriority(1)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.TransparentLogo)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetSound(soundUri);
 builder.Build();
```

The `URI` is the path to the resource where your sound file lives, then you set that `URI` in your `NotificationBuilder` using the `SetSound` method.

Comment: But, where do i use this? This works just for foreground notifications?

Comment: This is how you do both foreground and background notifications. In Android, they work the same way, you still need to call the `NotificationManager` to send a built notification. This sample code is directly from a push notification handler in a Xamarin.Android app.

Comment: my problem is, i haven't figured out, how to call the OnMessageReceived for background notifications, so i dont know, how to use the NotificationBulder for background notifications. I use Firebase, btw.

Comment: Did you set up the proper `Service`?